# nested dictionary with single key to data frame

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I have an output from yahoofinancials that is a single key nested dictionary:

```
all_stmnts_qt =  yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('quarterly', ['income', 'cash', 'balance'])
{'incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly': {'DDD': [{'2020-09-30': {'researchDevelopment': 18866000,
     'effectOfAccountingCharges': None,
     'incomeBeforeTax': -70023000,
     'minorityInterest': None,
     'netIncome': -72889000,
     'sellingGeneralAdministrative': 47207000,
     'grossProfit': 58627000,
     'ebit': -7446000,
     'operatingIncome': -7446000,
     'otherOperatingExpenses': None,
     'interestExpense': -611000,
     'extraordinaryItems': None,
     'nonRecurring': None,
     'otherItems': None,
     'incomeTaxExpense': 2866000,
     'totalRevenue': 135147000,
     'totalOperatingExpenses': 142593000,
     'costOfRevenue': 76520000,
     'totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet': -62577000,
     'discontinuedOperations': None,
     'netIncomeFromContinuingOps': -72889000,
     'netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares': -72889000}},
   {'2020-06-30': {'researchDevelopment': 16997000,...
```

and would like to make it into a data frame ideally as:
[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

I tried some solutions posted before (normalizing, flattening...) but I could only get to here:

```
incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2020-09-30_researchDevelopment_1    0   18866000.0
incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2020-09-30_incomeBeforeTax_1    0   -70023000.0
incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2020-09-30_netIncome_1  0   -72889000.0
incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2020-09-30_sellingGeneralAdministrative_1   0   47207000.0
incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2020-09-30_grossProfit_1    0   58627000.0
... ... ...
balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2019-12-31_netTangibleAssets_4 0   250645000.0
balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2019-12-31_netReceivables_4    0   109408000.0
balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2019-12-31_longTermDebt_4  0   45215000.0
balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2019-12-31_inventory_4 0   111106000.0
balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly_DDD_2019-12-31_accountsPayable_4   0   49851000.0
```

Comment: "I tried some solutions posted before" - what solutions did you already try?

Comment: Are the tags consistent throughout your file?  I would recommend using nested enumerate statements that extract the values of interest.